# aftermaths of a huge simultaneous and global powercut

Tags: society, electricity

We the scientists have discovered a space anomaly and we believe that this is the reason for our most disturbing problems.

Every time the angle between earth moon and sun in $(1)^{radian}$ we are shrouded in mysterious black. All our power and lighting systems fail *(across the world and simultaneously)* for X hours. we are unable to generate electricity and have to revert to archaic means. All forms of electric communications are done for. even though they *(as in everything that was disturbed)* come back to normal after every X hours. Something is very wrong.

We the people meanwhile try to live our happy lives. However these power cuts leave everyone baffled as to what is happening. sooner or later an astronomy enthusiast discovers that it all happens when angle between Sun-Earth-moon is $(1)^{radian}$. Now people become suspicious as to what is happening.

And this is the point where I become suspicious to:

- How people will react ?
- How governments handle the peoples' reaction ?

Comment: The technological pov would probably be way more interesting... as in: The whole infrastructure would collapse and the grid would overload.

Comment: @dot_Sp0T. What do you mean by a technical POV. I don't quite get it.

Comment: a thechnical `Point of View`. Electricity is not really something you can simply turn off and expect to turn on at a later point in time on such a big scale (unless you invoke *magic*)... It might be worth doing some investigations on the subjects of `blackout` and `brownout`

Comment: What is the worldbuilding problem here? This looks quite story based.

Comment: @JamesK this also looks very opinion based